# Couldn't select an option from menu items using cypress

Tags: cypress

hope you could help me in this issue!

The problem is I couldn't select an option from a dropdown. It's weird because I did the same code in other test and works fine.

This is the cypress code

```
cy.get('[data-cy=OptionSelectType]').click();
```

and here is the js code

```
            <MenuItem value='1'>Option 1</MenuItem>
            <MenuItem value='2'>Option 2</MenuItem>
            <MenuItem data-cy="OptionSelectType"value='3'>Option 3</MenuItem>
            <MenuItem value='4'>Option 4</MenuItem>
```

And the test shows this error

[image]

Thank you!

Comment: You seem to have mashed the `value` attribute into the `data-cy` attribute. What does the actual HTML end up as? Give a [mre].

Answer (score 1):

You need to use select method. Click method won't work for dropdowns:

cy.get('select').eq(2).should('be.visible').select('Option 3')